# how can I count strings?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

what should we do if we want to count specific string or int.
like I want to know how many 'p' in my list = ['hello world lets play ping pong]
is there any operator or method in python that I can use?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and take a quick [tour] to know how you can improve your post to get the maximum out of Stack Overflow!. Also, can you please fix the "my_list" by providing the actual input.

Comment: Are you looking for `str.count()`? check my answer below for links to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple for loop.

```py
count = 0
test_str = "hello world lets play ping pong"
  
for i in test_str:
    if i == 'p':
        count = count + 1
```

Or if you prefer you can do the following

```py
count = test_str.count('p')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what your list looks like since you have not provided a valid list.

However assuming that your list looks something like below, try this -

```
l = ['hello','world', 'lets', 'play', 'ping', 'pong']
sum([i.count('p') for i in l])
```

```
3
```

---

If its a string and not a list, then it's even simpler -

```
l = ['hello world lets play ping pong']
l[0].count('p')
```

```
3
```

Read more about `list.count()` method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp) or `str.count()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_count.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list with a String you can iterating the String with **list[*indexNumber*]**. Like:

```py
count = 0
listOfStrings = ["hello world lets play ping pong"] 

for i in listOfStrings[0]:
    if i == 'p':
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

**output: 3**

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. It is better to provide some textual explanation as well. Also, you are using the built-in name `list` as a variable name which is bad practice. You can edit your answer to improve it.